# how to open mediawiki database in phpmyadmin

Tags: database, phpmyadmin, apache2, mediawiki

I have just installed phpMyAdmin on my system and I want to access the MediaWiki database, but I can't see it in the left sidebar. I thought that I would be able to see the database automatically after installing phpMyAdmin, but it's not there.

What do I need to do to access the MediaWiki database in phpMyAdmin? Do I need to create the database manually, or is there a way to import it from MediaWiki?

I'm running phpMyAdmin version 8.2 and MediaWiki version 1.40.0 on operating system debian 12.

Thanks in advance for any help!